# In Javascript, why do return; when return nothing?

Tags: javascript

I thought, if return nothing in a function, then the function returns null itself.

but sometimes, I can see like this code,

```
function test() {
  // do something
  return;
}

var test = function() { 
  // do something
  return;

}
```

is the return; is necessary? then why?

Comment: well it does not return null, it returns undefined. Is it necessary? No, it is a preference.

Comment: Can confirm it's a preference, our linting standards require a return for functions unless X criteria. It's a decent practice, but you'll learn when it's obviously redundant or not needed

Comment: It ist not necessary. Return without return value can be used to leave a modul before the end of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `return;` does not return `null` but `undefined`
- When you see `return;` in a code, it's to **stop** the execution of the function before reaching its end. For example:

  ```
  function test(a) {
    if (a === 0) return;
    console.log(a);
  }
  ```

Here if the value of `a` is `0`, the console will not log. In other words, `test` will log anything given to it except the number 0.